# How to increment a multi-dimensional array value

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I am trying to increment the value of `caps` once it code sees that there is an event type of 10 or 11 in the loop. I am currently receiving an offset 1 error when I run the code, with the error being on the `$red_stats[$i]['caps'] = $red_stats[$i]['caps']+1` line.

I am trying to achieve an end array structure like the following:

```
$red_stats[$round]['caps']
```

I have the following code (everything else checks out except for the previously mentioned line.. as an added note, `$round_count` will evaluate to 2 so `$i` should evaluate to either `1` or `2`:

```
    $red_stats = [['caps'=>0]];
    array_pop($red_stats);

    for ($i = 1; $i <= $round_count; $i++)
    {
        foreach($events as $event)
        {
            if($event->event_type_id == 10 | $event->event_type_id == 11)
            {
                $red_stats[$i]['caps'] = $red_stats[$i]['caps'] + 1;
            }
        }
    }
    dd($red_stats);
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need to do this inside of the if ($event...) brackets:

```
if (isset($red_stats[$i]['caps']) && array_key_exists('caps', $red_stats[$i]))
{
  $red_stats[$i]['caps']++;
}
```

Comment: Hi I just tested this as well, it doesn't seem as the statement is qualifying as true, so `$red_stats[$i]['caps']` is never updated